# Transience of files in filesystem cache

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache, temporary-files

In my simplified understanding of a filesystem cache, files that are to be written to a disk mounted with the `async` option might not be immediately be written to disk, and can instead get smushed into a filesystem cache. Because the exact behaviour probably differs between configurations, my question is simply whether the following statement is true, false, or some combination thereof.

> Small files, such as temporary files, might never even be physically written to disk, especially if they are used and deleted quickly and before the next filesystem flush/sync occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, although for any individual file a little unlikely. It would depend on the filesystem, caching algorithm and other system activity.